# Sefer Hayashar Chelek Chiddushim

Tags: rabbeinu-tam

I'm looking for Sefer Hayashar Chelek Chiddushim free online. I need the part on Masechet Shabbat. In Hebrewboks that is some parts of it on Seder Nashim and Nezikin but not on Shabbat. Can someone show me where it's avaible?

Comment: It's availavble on the otzar hachochmo site but you would have to pay for the part on Shabbos - https://tablet.otzar.org/?lang=en#/b/627685/p/158/t/16570.5985495234731919/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40937&st=&pgnum=39

I assume you found this sefer before, just the order of the sefer is confusing. It starts with seder nashim, and only later comes back to Shabbos.

Comment: Interesting, when I read Zerachia Hayevani, I noticed that this name is mentioned for the Mussar Sefer Hayashar. Indeed this book is probably not from Rabenu Tam. Contrarily, that's absurd to attribute the Known Sefer Hayashar on Gemara to someone else. Main Rishonim quote it as Rabenu Tam book. Thank you.

Comment: The Numbers before the chapters aren't congruent with those cited in books. E.g. books cite 235 or 237 when in this book it's 129

Comment: Correct. There is great discrepancies in different editions of sefer hayashar. Most things that are cited today are from newer editions, that are more consistent. I posted the best edition I found on hebrewbooks.